# Scala - concatenate number of Try() results

Tags: scala

I have number of interfaces where each one of the returns Try() result.

For example:

```
def getElements1(id: Guid): Try[Seq[SpecialElement]] //From interface A
def getElements2(id: Guid): Try[Seq[SpecialElement]] //From interface B
def getElements3(id: Guid): Try[Seq[SpecialElement]] //From interface C
```

The all independent and can fail randomly.

What is the nicest 'Scala way' to concatenate their output with respect to Failure() case as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well... `nicest 'Scala way'` depends on what your requirements are ?

So... you have following 3 `def`s,

```
def getElements1(id: Guid): Try[Seq[SE]]
def getElements2(id: Guid): Try[Seq[SE]]
def getElements3(id: Guid): Try[Seq[SE]]
```

Case 1 - The result fails, if at least 1 of them fails and you get the error of only 1 failure.

```
val result: Try[Seq[SE]] = for {
  emements1 <- getElements1(id)
  emements2 <- getElements2(id)
  emements3 <- getElements3(id)
} yield emements1 ++ emements2 ++ emements3
```

Case 2 - The result fails, if at least 1 of them fails and you want to get the errors of all failures,

```
def trySeqToEither[T](tryTSeq: Seq[Try[T]]): Either[Seq[Throwable], Seq[T]] = {
  val accInit: Either[Seq[Throwable], Seq[T]] = Right(Seq.empty[T])

  tryTSeq.aggregate(accInit)({
    case (Right(seq), Success(t)) => Right(seq :+ t)
    case (Right(seq), Failure(ex)) => Left(Seq[Throwable](ex))
    case (Left(seq), Success(t)) => Left(seq)
    case (Left(seq), Failure(ex)) => Left(seq :+ ex) 
  })
}

val seqResultEither: Either[Seq[Throwable], Seq[Seq[SE]]]  = trySeqToEither(
    Seq(getElements1(id), getElements2(id), getElements3(id))
)

val resultEither: Either[Seq[Throwable], Seq[SE]] = seqResultEither match {
  case Right(seqResult) => Right(seqResult.flatten)
  case Left(seqThrowable) => Left(seqThrowable)
}
```

Case 3 - The result ignores the failed computations

```
val emementsOption1 = getElements1(id).toOption
val emementsOption1 = getElements2(id).toOption
val emementsOption3 = getElements3(id).toOption

val result: Seq[SE] = Seq[Seq[SE]](emementsOption1, emementsOption2, emementsOption3).flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use for comprehensions:

```scala
case class SpecialElement(x: Int)

val x: Try[Seq[SpecialElement]] = Try(List(SpecialElement(1)))
val y: Try[Seq[SpecialElement]] = Try(List(SpecialElement(2)))
val z: Try[Seq[SpecialElement]] = Try(List(SpecialElement(3)))

for {
  a <- x
  b <- y
  c <- z
} yield a ++ b ++ c 
Success(List(SpecialElement(1), SpecialElement(2), SpecialElement(3)))

for {
  a <- x
  b <- y
  c <- Try(throw new Exception)
} yield a ++ b ++ c 
Failure(java.lang.Exception)
```